# Conversion function from std::bind

Tags: c++

I am receiving an error when I create a new function from another using `std::bind` and trying to pass it to another function.

My code looks like

```
#include <functional>
using namespace std;
typedef double (*t_function)(double t, double *y);

double integrate_fmax(double s, bool(*t_max)(double t, double *y), void(*fce_min)(double s, double &t_0, double *y_0), t_function fce_max, double err, t_function *f_diff, int dim){...}

void get_x1_x2(double &x1, double &x2, double(*fce)(double x), double mlt){...}

double shoot_meth(double s1, double mlt, bool(*t_max)(double t, double *y), void(*fce_min)(double s, double &t_0, double *y_0), t_function fce_max, double err, t_function *f_diff, int dim){
    double s2;  
    auto fce_x = bind(integrate_fmax, placeholders::_1, t_max, fce_min, fce_max, err, f_diff, dim);
    get_x1_x2(s1, s2, fce_x, mlt);
}
```

I am receving error when I try pass function `fce_x` to `get_x1_x2`:

```
C2664: 'void get_x1_x2(double &,double &,double (__cdecl *)(double),double)' : cannot convert argument 3 from 'std::_Bind<true,double,double (__cdecl *const )(double,bool (__cdecl *)(double,double *),void (__cdecl *)(double,double &,double *),t_function,double,t_function *,int),std::_Ph<1> &,bool (__cdecl *&)(double,double *),void (__cdecl *&)(double,double &,double *),double (__cdecl *&)(double,double *),double &,t_function *&,int &>' to 'double (__cdecl *)(double)'
```

But when I tried something like `double foo = fce_x(5)` I get no error.

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013.

P.S. Sorry for ugly functions but I am not sure where is the error and that simplifying would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::bind` does not return a function pointer. You need to use `std::function` instead. This is because `std::bind` is only guaranteed to return something that can be stored in an `std::function`. If you replace

```
double(*fce)(double x)
```

with

```
std::function<double(double)> fce
```

it should work properly.